# Update field in multiple rows of slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

My grid (in dataView) contains a field "num", which shows the row number.
When I delete a row, the row numbers are no longer contiguous.
So I need to update this field for all rows to have a contiguous numbering.
(like in Excel, if you delete data in row 5, row number 5 doesn't disappear - only data shifts).

Question : How do I mass-update this field for all rows?
(if there is a quicker alternative - please let me know).

Comment: I wouldn't manage the row numbering. Instead I would use the grid's row number value and display it in the column dynamically using a custom formatter, since the row index is supplied as a parameter to the function.

Comment: I don't know what is custom formatter. Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you can leverage the row indexing used by the grid to dynamically render the row numbers via the [formatter](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Column-Options) column option. ([SlickGrid Examples](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example2-formatters.html))

The following code provides delete capability with dynamic row numbering. One important consideration is the use of a `slick.dataview` which requires [batching](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView#batching-updates) for multi-row deletes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/examples.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.dataview.js"></script>    
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.rowselectionmodel.js"></script>
    
<button id='deleteButton'>Delete Selected</button>
<div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
    
<script>
var grid;
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
var data = [];
var options = {
    editable: false,
    enableCellNavigation: true
};
var columns = [];
$(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var d = (data[i] = {});
        d[0] = "Row " + i;
        d.id = i
        d[1] = i
        d[Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 2)] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    }
    var checkboxSelector = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn({
        cssClass: "slick-cell-checkboxsel"
    });
    columns.push(checkboxSelector.getColumnDefinition());
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        columns.push({
            id: i,
            name: String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i),
            field: i,
            width: 100,
            formatter: i == 0 ? function(args){ return args} : null
        });
    }

    dataView.setItems(data)

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);
    grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({
        selectActiveRow: false
    }));
    grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector);
     
})

$('#deleteButton').click(function () {
    console.log("Delete")
    var selected = grid.getSelectedRows();
    grid.setSelectedRows([]);
    grid.getData().beginUpdate();
    $.each(selected, function (index, value) {
        console.log("Index: " + index)
        console.log("Value " + value)
        var id = grid.getData().getItem(value).id
        grid.getData().deleteItem(id) 
    })
    grid.getData().endUpdate();
    grid.invalidate()
});
</script>
```